# How to return a 2D array from a C function?

Tags: c, arrays, return

So I have to write a program that sorts a 2d array and then returns it but I just found out you cant return an array from a function. I tried researching this but nothing fixes the problem. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Below is the function I wrote to sort the vertical rows.

```
int vertSort(int matrix[][51], int size)
{
    for(c=0;c<size;c++)
    {

        for(r=0;r<size-1;r++)
        {
            if(matrix[c][r]>matrix[c][r+1])
            {
                printf("Swap row %d column %d with row %d column %d", r, c, r, c)
                int tmp=matrix[c][r];
                matrix[c][r]=matrix[c][r+1];
                matrix[c][r+1]=tmp;


            }

        }
    }
    return matrix;


}
```

Comment: Return? Why? You are passing this array into your function.

Comment: It can be returned as a 2D pointer. But still the r,c values are returned separately.

Comment: why dont you pass it as a reference.

Comment: Even if you could return an array from a function, it wouldn't do you any good, since you can't assign to arrays in C.

Comment: `for(r=0;r<size-1;r++)` does not match with `51` in the signature;  replace `size` by `51` or vice versa

Comment: You're using `r` for columns and `c` for rows, could be slightly confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not need to return anything, it modifies the caller's copy of the array.  (Arrays cannot be passed by value in C).  Change the `int` return type to `void` and all will be well.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I switched the int return type to void but now when I try and run the program I have an error at the bottom that says warning conflicting types for 'vertSort'

Comment: change it in the prototype also

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is impossibly messy, so I suggest using a typedef as shown below

```
typedef int (*ptr51)[51];

ptr51 vertSort( int matrix[][51], int size )
{
    matrix[0][2] = 99;
    matrix[1][1] = 88;
    return( matrix );
}

int main( void )
{
    int test[2][51] = { { 10, 20, 30 }, { 40, 50, 60 } };

    ptr51 output = vertSort( test, 0 );

    for ( int row = 0; row < 2; row++ )
    {
        for ( int col = 0; col < 3; col++ )
            printf( "%d ", output[row][col] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

Here is the impossibly messy syntax without a typedef

```
int (*(vertSort( int matrix[][51], int size )))[51]
{
    matrix[0][10] = 99;
    matrix[1][50] = 88;
    return( matrix );
}

int main( void )
{
    int test[2][51] = { { 10, 20, 30 }, { 40, 50, 60 } };

    int (*output)[51] = vertSort( test, 0 );

    for ( int row = 0; row < 2; row++ )
    {
        for ( int col = 0; col < 51; col++ )
            printf( "%d ", output[row][col] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

function's return type should be `int **` and typecast matrix to `int **`. It should work for you.

```
int** vertSort(int matrix[][51], int size)
{
     for(c=0;c<size;c++)
     {

        for(r=0;r<size-1;r++)
        {
             if(matrix[c][r]>matrix[c][r+1])
             {
                printf("Swap row %d column %d with row %d column %d", r, c, r, c)
                int tmp=matrix[c][r];
                matrix[c][r]=matrix[c][r+1];
                matrix[c][r+1]=tmp;


              }

         }
    }
    return (int **)matrix;


}
```

Comment: I think C will show error when `int [][51]` is accessed as `int **`.

Comment: To be pedantic, it's a warning, not an error (with clang, anyway), but you are of course right; it is bad practice to ignore warnings, so the explicit case is nice. +1

Comment: It's bad practice to ignore warnings, but a worse practice to cast them away. If the thing passed to `vertSort()` actually is a two-dimensional array, returning it as an `int **` and trying to access it via that pointer will be disastrous. If you actually are passing in an `int **`, you'll get the same problem in reverse. That warning is there for a good reason.

Comment: This is completely wrong, arrays are different to pointers. Silencing compiler warnings with a cast doesn't cause magic.